# Memory leaks when using closure

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, express

I'm using `express` and `node`, and add a middleware by myself in order to convert plain text to json object, the code is as follows:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   var tmpJson ='';
   req.setEncoding('utf8');
   req.on('data', function(chunk){
       tmpJson += chunk;
   });
   req.on('end', function(){
       req.json = JSON.parse(tmpJson);
       next();
       tmpJson = null;
   });
});
```

Will this code caused a memory leak? As far as I know, when using `req.json` in callback function of `end` event, it will increase a `count of usage` for `req`, and that will make this `req` never released?

If it does cause a memory leak, is there anyway I could avoid using this?

Comment: Most of all, I don't see why you need to do this, the bodyParser middleware handles that for you doesnt it ?

Comment: Agree with Louis, but if you want to avoid that, why not just set the chunk on the req object?  That's going to be reclaimed.

Comment: Well, `bodyParser` can not parse this for me, actually, when using `bodyParser`, it just returns `{'string occurred in chunks':}`, not convert `string occurred in chunks` into a `json` that I wanted.